# WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.5.78:8080/Chat-WebSocket/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: websocket

Hi Every One,
               I am trying to connect through web socket to replace  ajax log polling in my project as it has too much over head , tried a simple websocket chat code , issue is I cant make the handshake work on executing get following error in browser console
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.5.78:8080/Chat-WebSocket/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have setup my client code on local machine Client :

http://192.168.5.66/test/zaheer/Chat-WebSocket/

and server code  is on another local machine

192.168.5.78

here is my code

```
Client :
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    //create a new WebSocket object.
    var msgBox = $('#message-box');
    //var wsUri = "ws://192.168.5.78:8080/Chat-WebSocket/server.php";   
    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.5.78:8080/Chat-WebSocket/server.php");
    //websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

    websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
        msgBox.append('<div class="system_msg" style="color:#bbbbbb">Welcome to my "Demo WebSocket Chat box"!</div>'); //notify user
    }

    // Message received from server
    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var response        = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data

        var res_type        = response.type; //message type
        var user_message    = response.message; //message text
        var user_name       = response.name; //user name
        var user_color      = response.color; //color

        switch(res_type){
            case 'usermsg':
                msgBox.append('<div><span class="user_name" style="color:' + user_color + '">' + user_name + '</span> : <span class="user_message">' + user_message + '</span></div>');
                break;
            case 'system':
                msgBox.append('<div style="color:#bbbbbb">' + user_message + '</div>');
                break;
        }
        msgBox[0].scrollTop = msgBox[0].scrollHeight; //scroll message 

    };

    websocket.onerror   = function(ev){ msgBox.append('<div class="system_error">Error Occurred - ' + ev.data + '</div>'); };

    websocket.onclose   = function(ev){ msgBox.append('<div class="system_msg">Connection Closed</div>'); }; 

    //Message send button
    $('#send-message').click(function(){
        send_message();
    });

    //User hits enter key 
    $( "#message" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
      if(event.which==13){
          send_message();
      }
    });

    //Send message
    function send_message(){
        var message_input = $('#message'); //user message text
        var name_input = $('#name'); //user name

        if(message_input.val() == ""){ //empty name?
            alert("Enter your Name please!");
            return;
        }
        if(message_input.val() == ""){ //emtpy message?
            alert("Enter Some message Please!");
            return;
        }

        //prepare json data
        var msg = {
            message: message_input.val(),
            name: name_input.val(),
            color : '<?php echo $colors[$color_pick]; ?>'
        };
        //convert and send data to server
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));    
        message_input.val(''); //reset message input
    }
</script>


Server :

<?php 
$host = '192.168.5.78'; //host
$port = '8080'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text, true); //json decode 
            $user_name = $tst_msg['name']; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg['message']; //message text
            $user_color = $tst_msg['color']; //color

            //prepare data to be sent to client
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));
            send_message($response_text); //send data
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

Comment: How are you running the server?

Comment: using Apache :http://192.168.5.66/test/zaheer/Chat-WebSocket

Comment: i have two local machine one i am using as client and the other as server

Comment: That won’t start the *server*. You have to have it running so you can connect to it. Meaning your PHP server script has to run before you try to connect.

Comment: server is already in running state: using xampp control panel

Comment: Not Apache server. The server.php you’ve written. It needs to run before you connect to it.

Comment: yes you are right i tried it connects then

Comment: so will start my web socket server through ajax before i make the handshake request when the client page load for the first time?

Comment: You could, but it’s going to be complex, very easily broken, and I would never recommend using it in any real world application. A proper websocket server would be a lot easier and work a lot better, or even running the PHP server separately

Comment: is there any other way to keep server in running state all the time?

Comment: How can i set up a proper web server any examples ?